# scp a folder to my ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

I have a folder on my mac that I need to move over to my server. I can ssh in the server but how do i get this folder up....

say I am on my local computer and the folder is named shared and I want to put it on the server in /srv/www/somesite/current. How do i enter the password in my scp command

I found this but i dont think its right

```
scp -r shared/* matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current/shared
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scp -r shared matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current/
```

That should get the job done (assuming "shared" is in your CWD) if the server support scp, which it likely will by default. You'll be asked for you password from STDIN after issuing the command.